# binary_crossentrophy vs categorical_crossentropy

Tags: python, cross-entropy

I have a dataset with 10 categorical features and one output feature with class 0 and 1. X_train follows a 3D array so I have done label encoding beforehand on the dataset.
I have applied categorical_crossentrophy but I am getting 26% accuracy with activation function sigmoid. When I apply binary_crossentrophy, the accuracy drastically increased to 98%.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(256, input_shape=(n_timesteps,n_features),recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(16))
model.add(Dense(n_outputs, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

and dataset is divided as:

```
X_train:  (430000, 5, 10)
y_train:  (430000, 1)
```

I am confused if I am doing the right thing. Please suggest!!

Comment: try changing the activation function of last layer to softmax in case of categorical cross entropy.

Comment: @MuhammadAhmed,but the class is 0 and 1 so can I apply softmax in such case?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to predict 10 different classes, you will need to use the categorical_crossentropy. The final output layer must have 10 units with the softmax activation function. The binary_crossentrophy is for binary classification like cat and dog, or yes or no.